# Windows 10: Can you configure the mapping of processes to "Applications" in Task Manager?

Tags: windows, task-manager

Is there a configuration file or registry thing or maybe even a tool to change which processes are attributed to which "Application" in Task Manager?   I would like to map all the compiler drivers spawned by Visual Studio to its total, but they aren't tied to it by parent process.  I would be happy to just be able to map it by process executable name.

Similarly, it would be nice to be able to say which other processes should be combined and shown, even if they aren't associated with a foreground window.

Maybe I just need a better task manager...

Comment: Maybe try SysInternals , Process Explorer.  I use this and it may do what you want.

Comment: Yeah I use all the SysInternals tools.  But it doesn't seem to have the feature of "pretend MSBuild.exe is a child of MSDEV.exe" (for example) either.  I wanted to map things not just based on PPID so the CPU etc. totals make sense.

Comment: I don't believe that the task manager "fakes" child processes.  What you are describing has to do with the flags that [CreateProcess](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa) was called with.  Specifically, look at the [process creation flags](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/process-creation-flags).  A "better task manager" wouldn't lie about child processes.

Comment: In my question I specifically asked for configuration to let me make it lie.  As in... I want to attribute the resource usage of certain forked processes (msbuild, cl, etc.) to Visual Studio,  even though they don't have that parent process ID.   Just to make it more intuitive when you pop the resource usage and your CPUs are pegged by build processes that aren't attributed to any running app.

Comment: I'm certainly no expert or even half as experienced as the people who have already commented, but if your goal is to group these processes under the Visual Studio tag I ask if it's because you want to selectively monitor the consumption of system resources for those specific processes under your own custom roof? If yes, then you might find what you're looking for in perfmon by creating your own custom performance counter task encompassing all those individual processes.

Comment: I'm referring to Run Menu > perfmon

Comment: Yes, that would solve the problem as I have stated it.  I just wanted to make it work in the casual Task Manager view.   Sometimes Windows applications are actually much more configurable than the UI suggests, so I was hoping maybe the rules the Task Manager uses to group things could be configurable in the registry or hacking a file.  Oh well.